# showing that $G=N\rtimes C$ for some subgroup $C$ of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be a group and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/N\cong\mathbb{Z}$.
>
> Show that $G=N\rtimes C$ for some subgroup $C$ of $G$.

Comment: Are you sure it's $N\ltimes C$ and not $N\rtimes C$?

Comment: oh yes its is $N\rtimes C$

Comment: Hint: Pick $x\in G$ mapping to $1\in\mathbb Z$ and let $C=\langle x\rangle$.